# Is there a way to replace empty array structs with nulls in Spark SQL?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I tried to find empty array structs in spark sql using the following:

spark.sql("""
select count(*) from table1
where size(arraycolumn1) = 0
""").show()

but no luck. Is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
spark.sql(""" select count(*) from table1 where arraycolumn1 is null """).show()
```